# Azure App Service - Application setting Value from an Environment Variable (Variable as Value in .JSON )

Tags: json, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

let we create a new WebApp and turn on the In-App MySQL. As we know, the DbPort can be changed at a restart of the app, so it is suggested to use variables instead static settings. Here we have not only the \data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb but the system variable WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT. With the getenv('WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT') syntax it works perfect.

NOw I have a PHP code, uses the getenv('DB_PORT') syntax. It comes from a GIT Repository that i don't want to change. But i want to use variables.

When I use the Portal and set by Configuration>Application settings a new one as {"name": "DB_PORT", "value": "WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT"} then getenv('DB_PORT') returns the text value WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT and not the portnumber.

What is wrong here? How to put the value of a system variable into an app setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the application settings with

```
{"name": "DB_PORT", "value": "WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT"}
```

**getenv('DB_PORT')** will return "WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT", and this is the expected result.

As far as I know there is no such way to refer to another environment variable in the **value** of application settings. It is recommended that you use `getenv('WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT')` in your code.

Comment: Yes it seams, that in Azure the Value of this settings can only be a static string and not a dynamic variable. Maybe web.config can solve the situation...